# in js, why is my filereader unable to track my inputfile when I edited it

Tags: javascript, html, file

Maybe naive question but I'm wondering this:

I have an html input allowing me to find a local file on my computer. `<input type="file" id="importFile">`

From this input, i create a FileReader in js to display the text file content on my page

```
var search_file = document.getElementById("search_file")
search_file.addEventListener('change', function(){
var reader = new FileReader();
var tmp = [];
reader.readAsText(file_to_survey);
reader.onload = function(e) {
   var contents = e.target.result;
   //function to edit html thanks to content//
}, false);
```

This part is actually working well BUT if I edit or replace the file I targeted (with exact same file name), I'm not able to display the file without to search it again with the html input mentionned above.

Is there a way to keep trace of my file even after edition?

Many thanks for your help. I dug quiet a lot to solve my problem but maybe I'm thinking the wrong way. Any clue would be nice.

Comment: What do you mean, _“without to search it again”_? Who is doing any “searching” here, where and how? Are you simply talking about opening the file selection dialog, and then selecting the exact same file you had already previously selected, again? Well in that case, probably not all browsers will fire the `change` event to begin with. (But then you should still see your previous result, so I am really not sure what the problem is supposed to be here.)

Comment: "_with exact same file name_" --> onchange will never trigger on this case, because the selected file is not actually changed. Also, all changes you do to the file input field manually/programmatically are ignored (except emptying the field). If you need to reload the file, run the change function directly.

Comment: The file I target dinamicaly change over time. It contains logs from a scanner i'm using in a lab. When i first get the file thanks to the html input, i can display what it contains. No problem. But once my scanner edited or overwrite the file, i cant' just repeat my js junction again, I also have to target my file again with the html input.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how the `input type=file` element works, and to my best knowledge there is no way for you to force the browser to automatically re-read a file from the user's hard drive without their express consent.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the change handler of the file input in a separate function, and call that function when needed.

```js
function loadFile () {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', function () {
    file = reader.result;
    // Handle the changes here
    console.log(file);
  });
  reader.readAsText(fileField.files[0]);
}

const fileField = document.getElementById('load'),
  reloadBut = document.getElementById('reload');
let file;

reloadBut.addEventListener('click', loadFile);
fileField.addEventListener('change', loadFile);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="load">
<button id="reload">Load</button>
```

A separate button is used to reload the file in this snippet, but you can call `loadFile` where ever you need, ex. in an interval or from some event handler knowing the file was changed etc.

**Note**: This works in Chrome only, other browsers seem to lose the reference to the file browsed into file input when the file is changed. Also, the file must be properly closed after saving, before reloading.